# Memory allocation to string variable

Tags: java

Please confirm which of the two codes are efficient a or b . Where string is defines inside loop or outside loop.
Kindly sugggest.

a)

```
for(int i=0;i<configIndexNumber.size();i++){
                     ConfigurationDetailsObject oldIndex =(ConfigurationDetailsObject)configIndexNumber.get(i);
                     String Key = oldIndex.getVehConfigNo()+oldIndex.getBaseEngineKey()+oldIndex.getEngineCode()+oldIndex.getTestGroupId()+oldIndex.getTransConfig()+oldIndex.getInertiaWeightClassNo()+oldIndex.getAxleRatioValue();
                        if(!configIdxNnb.containsKey(Key))
                        {
                                newConfigIndexList.add(oldIndex);
                                configIdxNnb.put(Key,oldIndex);
                        }

                 }
```

b)

```
String Key=null;

 for(int i=0;i<configIndexNumber.size();i++){
                     ConfigurationDetailsObject oldIndex =(ConfigurationDetailsObject)configIndexNumber.get(i);
                     Key = oldIndex.getVehConfigNo()+oldIndex.getBaseEngineKey()+oldIndex.getEngineCode()+oldIndex.getTestGroupId()+oldIndex.getTransConfig()+oldIndex.getInertiaWeightClassNo()+oldIndex.getAxleRatioValue();
                        if(!configIdxNnb.containsKey(Key))
                        {
                                newConfigIndexList.add(oldIndex);
                                configIdxNnb.put(Key,oldIndex);
                        }

                 }
```

Comment: I would focus on making your code more *readable* (and following Java naming conventions) before you worry about performance - and please put more effort into formatting questions in future. (I'd also use a separate class for the key, rather than just using string concatenation.)

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between the two cases. In both cases you are assigning a new value to the String variable.

I know what optimization you have in mind. That kind of optimization is routinely done by compilers these days. But again, it doesn't apply in your case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a minor difference  in memory aspect. JVM is enough intelligent to manage.

But you should declare a variable in the smallest scope required . i.e the first case is looking good to me.

I did'nt remember the exact quote from efffective java, It goes something like

> The Garbage collector do the best when we use smallest  possible scope.

But if you want to access that variable outside the loop the second is the option.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C++ ,Local variables need not be initialised separately in java prior to the scope in which it is being used. So there is no need for initialising

```
String Key = null
```

prior to its usage. It is a better programming practice to initialise a local variable only when it is used . It is also efficient in a certain sense that you allocate memory for the variable in the heap only when it is being put to use inside the for loop.

Refer the oracle docs for greater understanding on variable initialisations

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter in terms of efficiency, but (a) is the better of the two - it is better for code readability to define variables in the smallest possible scope.

Answer (score 0):

> There is very little/ negligible difference b/w the execution times
>   of the 2... The compiler optimizes your code...

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long l = System.nanoTime();
        func1("hi");
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime()-l);
        long l1 = System.nanoTime();
        func2("hi");
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime()-l1);
    }

    public static void func1(String str)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
        {
            String s= str ;
        //  System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static void func2(String str)
    {String s= null;
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
        {
             s= str ;
        //  System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}

O/p : 
1. 277530
   265557

2. 267694
  243747
```